# Fastest Way to load Large SQL Tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I am making a ASP.NET website that displays data to the user. It queries an sql database to get that data, then displays it in the browser. The tables are often 1 million + rows, and take some time to load. Rather than the user having to wait that long to view the page, I would like the page to load, then the data is added to the page as it is loaded. I can achieve this with SignalR, but my question is:

In C#, is there a way to say "select * from tableName", but have it return the lines one by one, and is this the fastest way to load the data?

Comment: I don't know if entity framework provides loading data line by line, but loading 1 million +rows in browser is quite memory burden. My approach to this would be to provide paging to user say 10 or 20 records at first. Then on going to next or previous page you can filter out next set of records. This way user experience will not hamper and you would need not to load entire data at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option you can do is list by pages, which helps in loading,

```
   string searchString

   if (searchString != null)
   {
       page = 1;
   }
   else
   {
       searchString = currentFilter;
   }

   ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

   int pageSize = 5;
   int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
   return View(Users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

if you can decrease the volume of data to be loaded it would be, the best, in my case I did a "select" to load only lines with a certain value

```
var VAR = db.YourModel.Where(x => x.YourColumn  == YourString/Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this would probably be to create a server side method that is called asynchronously through Ajax, and load into a table. That way the action that loads the view isn't reliant on the table loading, and the table records will load as they  come in.
Also, If the data doesn't change very frequently, consider caching it to make subsequent page loads much faster.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR will work for this scenario, there are two points while loading large data sets from db.

1. Never use *, instead name each and every column name that you want.
2. You can first get the count of the records in the table and then fetch based on the batch size. For example you have 1000 records in DB, and your batch size is 100. So you will make 10 requests to DB to fetch all the 1000 elements.